# Java - How to use the string.format() to replace any string concatenation within a Sql statement creation?

Tags: java, sql

How would I use string.format() to omit the + string concatenation + in this Java/SQL code.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM "+p_tableName+" WHERE 1 = 0";
```

Comment: Your condition is surprising. `(1 = 0)`? Anyways, what have you tried?

Comment: The 1=0 is odd, but it's not too uncommon.  I've seen it used a lot where for some reason you want to execute but don't want results.  Usually it's a test thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE 1 = 0", p_tableName);
```

Always be careful when making SQL statements this way as they can very easily be used against you in SQL injection attacks.

Comment: For any String.format commands you must escape out any existing % symbols. These symbols are often used in LIKE operations.

Comment: How would I "ESCAPE" out of the %   What does that mean?

Comment: Would this escape be more applicable here.

Comment: select count(userfieldid) from tr_userfield where calcexpression like '%" + match + "%'and usefor like '%" + useFor +"%'"

Comment: @user1865053 In java `%` is escaped by writing: `%%`

Comment: So use                                                                                      String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM %%s WHERE 1 = 0", p_tableName);

Comment: @user1865053 no what I listed above is correct, %s will be replaced by the string p_tableName, if you wanted a % in the actual query such as `WHERE Column1 like '%%test%%'` you would use 2 %'s since you actually want the % character in the query that case.

Comment: So is this what he is talking about; to use string.format() to omit the + string concatenation + in this Java/SQL code and then in any String.format commands you must escape out any existing % symbols........      String sql = String.format("SELECT last_name FROM %s WHERE last_name LIKE '%% %s %%' ", p_tableName, match);.......

Comment: @user1865053 looks about right, but again be careful if the user has any control over what is in your 2 variables or you might be an easy target for SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE 1 = 0", table_name)`. But, I strongly advise you to use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead (See [How do I make a prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3700495/130224), https://stackoverflow.com/a/396765/130224, [PreparedStatements and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/687550/130224), and [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)). [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) yields higher performance and security.

Comment: I am performing a data migration and moving an embedded SQL statement into a static constant then JUnit testing it to compare the migration of the data against a source and target database.

Comment: He can't use a PreparedStatement to fill in the table in his scenario. What other tool are available to do just that?

Comment: @Damien is correct.  PreparedStatement doesn't allow control of the table name.  This answer doesn't apply to the question.