# Insert not working properly

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have the following code in my application

```
    public int insert_dependente(Dependente dependente) {
    ResultSet r;
    int result = 0;
    if (!(dependente == null)) {
        try {
            Connection conn = new Conexao().getConnection();
            String sql = "insert into Dependente "
                    + "(IdAssoc,"
                    + "NomeDep,"
                    + "SobrenomeDep,"
                    + "RgDep,"
                    + "CpfDep,"
                    + " DtNascDep,"
                    + " emailDep,"
                    + " tipoDep,"
                    + " DtCriacaoDep)"
                    + " VALUES (" + dependente.getAssociado() + ","
                    + "'" + dependente.getNome() + "',"
                    + "'" + dependente.getSobrenome() + "',"
                    + "'" + dependente.getRg() + "',"
                    + "'" + dependente.getCpf() + "',"
                    //+ new java.sql.Date(dependente.getNascimento().getTime()).toString() + ","
                    + "'" + dependente.getEmail() + "',"
                    + "'" + dependente.getTipoDep() + "'";
                    //+ new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime()).toString() + ")";
            Statement state; 
            state = conn.createStatement();
            state.execute(sql);
            state.close();

            String sql2 = "SELECT IdDep FROM Dependente WHERE CpfDep = " + dependente.getCpf();
            state = conn.createStatement();
            r = state.executeQuery(sql2);
            while (r.next()) {
                result = r.getInt("idAssoc");
            }
            r.close();
            state.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DependenteDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that the values are never inserted in my database.
And when the system reaches the line

```
state.execute(sql);
```

the system ignores everything and jump straight to the line

```
return result;
```

I've tried everything but I can't find my error.
Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Your SQL insert statement is missing the closing bracket!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume, executing your SQL statement raises an exception. It should be somewhere in the log, as you catch it and log it.

The reason: Your SQL insert statement is missing the closing bracket: ).

Apart from that, it is easier and safer to use a `PreparedStatement` instead of programatically concatenating the final SQL statement out of several variables (see also [Should I be using PreparedStatements for all my database inserts in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396749/should-i-be-using-preparedstatements-for-all-my-database-inserts-in-java) for the reason):

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Dependente" +   
             + " (IdAssoc, NomeDep, SobrenomeDep, RgDep, CpfDep, DtNascDep, emailDep, tipoDep, DtCriacaoDep)" +
             + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

try (PrepareStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    pstmt.setLong(1, dependente.getAssociado());
    pstmt.setString(2, dependente.getNome());
    pstmt.setString(3, dependente.getSobrenome());
    ...

    pstmt.executeUpdate();
} // automatically closes statement (see try-with-resource above)
```

Answer (score 2):

You commented out the bracket at the end of your INSERT statement:

```
 String sql = "insert into Dependente "
     + "(IdAssoc,"
     + "NomeDep,"

    ...

    //+ new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime()).toString() + ")";
```

This is why you get an `SQLException` and your code execution is interrupted. You even pass the exception on to your logger, you should be able to find it in your logs:

```
Logger.getLogger(DependenteDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

Use this code instead:

```
String sql = "insert into Dependente "
    + "(IdAssoc,"
    + "NomeDep,"
    + "SobrenomeDep,"
    + "RgDep,"
    + "CpfDep,"
    + " DtNascDep,"
    + " emailDep,"
    + " tipoDep,"
    + " DtCriacaoDep)"
    + " VALUES (" + dependente.getAssociado() + ","
    + "'" + dependente.getNome() + "',"
    + "'" + dependente.getSobrenome() + "',"
    + "'" + dependente.getRg() + "',"
    + "'" + dependente.getCpf() + "',"
    + "'" + dependente.getEmail() + "',"
    + "'" + dependente.getTipoDep() + "')";
```